# PHP, MySQL - Trouble downloading uploaded file from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when downloading a file previously uploaded into database, instead of downloading said file the computer downloads a 'download.php' file which is the script to download. I am using some kind of identifier like 'download.php?id=1' to pick and download specific file, and yes, I am aware this code is probably deprecated and not secure.

This is download.php I type:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$namatemp=$_SESSION['nama'];
$nistemp=$_SESSION['nislogin'];
$kelastemp=$_SESSION['kelas'];
$mapeltemp=$_SESSION['mapeltemp'];
$chapteridtemp=$_SESSION['chapteridtemp'];

$query=("SELECT mime, name, size, data FROM file WHERE uploader='$namatemp' AND chapter='$chapteridtemp')");
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row=1) {
header('Content-Type: '.$row['mime']);
header('Content-Length: '.$row['size']);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$row['name']);
echo $row['name'];
} else {
    echo "You have not uploaded such file."; 
}
?>
```

Comment: you don't output the file

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: plus try to remove the superfluous `chapter='$chapteridtemp')` closing parenthesis in the query. `if($row=1) {` assignment instead of comparison

Comment: Doesn't ``header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$row['name']);`` outputs the file? then ``echo $row['name'];`` calls it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add:

```
readfile($row['name']);
```

Yet I think you better check in that page is the file exist to redirect to a download page and if it does not exist, printing the error, because I'm not so sure if the headers can be nested in an if statement. Of course, I might be wrong and get downvoted for saying this.

Comment: Look at [Ghost's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350609/php-mysql-trouble-downloading-uploaded-file-from-database#comment43155627_27350609), then look at OP's code again, *very carefully*.